# What is the etymology of the term "amplitude" as used in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, terminology, history

[Some people](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/scott-aaronson-answers-every-ridiculously-big-question-i-throw-at-him/) claim that the *single* most important conceptual point in all of quantum mechanics is that "probability amplitudes" (inner products) can be complex, as opposed to strictly positive. But in the earlier theory of classical wave mechanics, an inherent feature of wave amplitudes is that they are always positive. So from this perspective, calling a quantum-mechanical inner product a probability "amplitude" seems like uniquely misleading terminology. What is the historical origin of the term?

Comment: Maybe a question for [hsm.se]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about etymology of a word.

Comment: @Qmechanic Are questions about the history of physics or etymology off-topic? Searching Physics SE for "etymology" results in dozens of questions about etymology, none of which are closed. I checked before I asked.

Comment: @Qmechanic The [community consensus](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic) seems to be that history of physics questions are on-topic, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Qmechanic Unilateral closure seems rather too strong for this one, but if it was to be closed it could just as well have been migrated to hsm.

Comment: The word _amplitude_ (like the word _wavefunction_) is presumably loosely based on notions from the theory of waves.

Comment: @qmechanic: it seems no worse than the question on projectiles, wind & game-playing that came up recently - double standards, perhaps?

Comment: @MoziburUllah and others: On/off-topic is in principle an absolute (as opposed to a relative) notion. If one finds another question that is off-topic, please vote-to-close or flag.

Comment: @qmechanic: I'm not sure I follow; the use of language without a subject implies objectivity, this is a characteristic of scientific language and gestures to the objectivity of its findings in understanding how nature itself, a non-human domain, works; however, to settle whether a topic is on-topic or off-topic requires human discretion, to that extent, it can never be fully objective, and retains an element of the subjective; to that extent, it cannot be wholly absolute, but retains a measure of the relative.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) is a term used in descriptions of sinusoidal functions, where the y variable is the "amplitude" in various descriptions  and the x may be space or time. It is used in describing waves in general, as waves  are =modeled with differential equations called wave equations.

[image: ampl]

> A sinusoidal curve
>
> 1. Peak amplitude
>
> 2.Peak-to-peak amplitude
>
> 3. Root mean square amplitude
>
> 4.Wave period (not an amplitude)

The usage in physics follows the convention of wave descriptions.You ask:

> So from this perspective, calling a quantum-mechanical inner product a probability "amplitude" seems like uniquely misleading terminology. What is the historical origin of the term?

The historical reason comes from the interference effects seen in the probability density distributions from quantum mechanical systems, clearly seen as interference patterns in [double slit experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), characteristic of wave solutions.

[image: dblsslit]

Particularly the single electron or photon at a time, established that the sinusoidal solutions of the quantum mechanical equations and the rule of using the complex conjugate squared for describing the probability of measuring a particle at an (x,y,z) was a solid prediction, and that the [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html#c2) for choosing the quantum mechanical solutions of boundary conditions problems were valid.